# Destroying all information on elasticsearch and starting fresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I recently attempted to use elasticsearch and search kick in a rails 4 application. I had generated a cluster with one index and I'd like to delete all information and start from scratch, however, I cannot seem to do so. When I start the ES server it is frozen with pending tasks trying to initialize shards.

I've tried brew remove elasticsearch and reinstalling
I've tried spinning up the ES server and running:

`$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'`

to no avail. It simply adds another pending task.

Any suggestions on how to wipe the slate clean and start from scratch?

*****EDIT*****

My problem came from having previously spun up an ES server on another branch with the same cluster name. This is what I believe caused an (for lack of understand the real cause/issue) endless loop of ES trying to initialize a new shard, failing, and retrying. Answer below to how I started completely fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wipe the slate clean I did the following:

After `$ brew install elasticsearch` I ran `$ brew info elasticsearch` to gain the path to the config file.

In the config.yml file I changed the name of the cluster, the name of the node, and the mlock setting to true per the advice of this seemingly recent and relevant video from ES: https://www.elastic.co/webinars/get-started-with-elasticsearch/?baymax=rtp&elektra=videos&storm=video1&iesrc=ctr

If you're looking to start fresh, this worked perfectly for me.

All other steps per the ES docs and searchkick docs work smashingly.

Answer (score 1):

As per searchkick's documentation you can clean your indices using the following method.

`Product.clean_indices` to remove your old indices.

or change the name of your index to start fresh by adding this to your model.

`searchkick index_name: "products_v2"`

Read more [here](http://searchkick.org/)

Comment: I really appreciate this answer and this would normally serve as a correct answer, but the problem was not with searchkick, rather, elasticsearch and thus could not use the searhkick commands to resolve the issue.